# deal with algebraic loop in distributed control algorithm

Tags: control-engineering, automotive-engineering, mathematics

Recently I found a [distributed control method](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8329591) for multi-agent system, which implements an algebraic loop like:
$$
u_{i}=(l_{ii}+b_{i})^{-1}\left [{\sum _{j\neq i}a_{ij}u_{j} -\mu e_{2i}+b_{i} u_{0} }\right]
$$
Briefs for graph theory, $A=\left[a_{ij}\right]$ is the adjacency matrix, $d_{i}=\sum_{j=1,j\ne i}a_{ij}$, $D=diag(d_{i})$, is the degree matrix, and $L=D-A$ is the Laplacian matrix.

The extended control law of the overall MAS can be written as
$$
u = \left[(D+B)^{-1}\otimes I_n\right] \left[(A\otimes I_{n}) u - {\mu e_{2}+b\otimes u_{0} }\right]
$$
By multiplying $\left[(D+B)\otimes I_n\right]$ to the both side, one has
$$
\left[(D+B)\otimes I_n\right] u = (A\otimes I_{n}) u - {\mu e_{2}+b\otimes u_{0} }
$$
Rearranging the sequence of the terms yields (*This is where the algebraic loop is introduced*)
$$
\left[(L+B)\otimes I_n\right] u = - {\mu e_{2}+b\otimes u_{0} }
$$
Further, one has
$$
u = \left[\left ({L+B}\right)^{-1}\otimes I_{n}\right] \cdot \left ({-\mu e_{2}+b\otimes u_{0}}\right)
$$

NOTICE that calculating $u_i$ requires $u_j$, and calculating $u_j$ requires $u_i$, which means there exists an **algebraic loop** in the control method. How can it possible to solve the control protocol in practice?

- Some say that it should be considered in a discrete case, which calculates $u_i(k)$ with $u_j(k-1)$.
- Some say that a filter could be used to avoid this problem (Eq.14 in [Distributed Finite-Time Fault-Tolerant Containment Control for Multiple Unmanned Aerial Vehicles](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8793238)).

Comment: Are $l_{ii}, b_i, a_{ij}, \mu, b$ constants ? if so, is the first equation linear in the terms $u_i, u_j$ ? Then the problem is that of solving a set of linear equations. (Even if not not), there may be iterative methods to solve these algebraic loops.

Comment: Thanks! All of them are constants. I know the iteration method is one of the solutions. The distributed control of MAS rejects this solution because iteration requires multiple interactions among agents to find a solution. However, the communications cost too many resources. I wonder if there exists any approcimation method for this problem.